# Extract words from a column and count frequency

Tags: sql, sql-server

Does anyone know if there's an efficient way to extract all the words from a single column and count the frequency of each word in SQL Server? I only have read-only access to my database so I can't create a self-defined function to do this.

Here's a reproducible example:

```
CREATE TABLE words 
(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    text_column VARCHAR(1000)
);

INSERT INTO words (id, text_column)
VALUES
    (1, 'SQL Server is a popular database management system'),
    (2, 'It is widely used for data storage and retrieval'),
    (3, 'SQL Server is a powerful tool for data analysis');
```

I have found this code but it's not working correctly, and I think it's too complicated to understand:

```
WITH E1(N) AS 
(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM (VALUES
           (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
         ) t(N)
),
E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a CROSS JOIN E1 b),
E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a CROSS JOIN E2 b)
SELECT
    LOWER(x.Item) AS [Word],
    COUNT(*) AS [Counts]
FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM words) a
CROSS APPLY 
    (SELECT 
         ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
         Item       = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(a.text_column, l.N1, l.L1)))
     FROM 
         (SELECT 
              s.N1,
              L1 = ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(' ',a.text_column,s.N1),0)-s.N1,4000)
          FROM
              (SELECT 1 
               UNION ALL
               SELECT t.N+1 
               FROM
                   (SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(a.text_column)/2,0))
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
                    FROM E4) t(N)
               WHERE SUBSTRING(a.text_column ,t.N,1) = ' '
              ) s(N1)
        ) l(N1, L1)
) x
WHERE 
    x.item <> '' 
    AND x.Item NOT IN ('0o', '0s', '3a', '3b', '3d', '6b', '6o', 'a', 'a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'ab', 'able', 'about', 'above', 'abst', 'ac', 'accordance', 'according', 'accordingly', 'across', 'act', 'actually', 'ad', 'added', 'adj', 'ae', 'af', 'affected', 'affecting', 'affects', 'after', 'afterwards', 'ag', 'again', 'against', 'ah', 'ain', 'ain''t', 'aj', 'al', 'all', 'allow', 'allows', 'almost', 'alone', 'along', 'already', 'also', 'although', 'always', 'am', 'among', 'amongst', 'amoungst', 'amount', 'an', 'and', 'announce', 'another', 'any', 'anybody', 'anyhow', 'anymore', 'anyone', 'anything', 'anyway', 'anyways', 'anywhere', 'ao', 'ap', 'apart', 'apparently', 'appear', 'appreciate', 'appropriate', 'approximately', 'ar', 'are', 'aren', 'arent', 'aren''t', 'arise', 'around', 'as', 'a''s', 'aside', 'ask', 'asking', 'associated', 'at', 'au', 'auth', 'av', 'available', 'aw', 'away', 'awfully', 'ax', 'ay', 'az', 'b', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'ba', 'back', 'bc', 'bd', 'be', 'became', 'because', 'become', 'becomes', 'becoming', 'been', 'before', 'beforehand', 'begin', 'beginning', 'beginnings', 'begins', 'behind', 'being', 'believe', 'below', 'beside', 'besides', 'best', 'better', 'between', 'beyond', 'bi', 'bill', 'biol', 'bj', 'bk', 'bl', 'bn', 'both', 'bottom', 'bp', 'br', 'brief', 'briefly', 'bs', 'bt', 'bu', 'but', 'bx', 'by', 'c', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'ca', 'call', 'came', 'can', 'cannot', 'cant', 'can''t', 'cause', 'causes', 'cc', 'cd', 'ce', 'certain', 'certainly', 'cf', 'cg', 'ch', 'changes', 'ci', 'cit', 'cj', 'cl', 'clearly', 'cm', 'c''mon', 'cn', 'co', 'com', 'come', 'comes', 'con', 'concerning', 'consequently', 'consider', 'considering', 'contain', 'containing', 'contains', 'corresponding', 'could', 'couldn', 'couldnt', 'couldn''t', 'course', 'cp', 'cq', 'cr', 'cry', 'cs', 'c''s', 'ct', 'cu', 'currently', 'cv', 'cx', 'cy', 'cz', 'd', 'd2', 'da', 'date', 'dc', 'dd', 'de', 'definitely', 'describe', 'described', 'despite', 'detail', 'df', 'di', 'did', 'didn', 'didn''t', 'different', 'dj', 'dk', 'dl', 'do', 'does', 'doesn', 'doesn''t', 'doing', 'don', 'done', 'don''t', 'down', 'downwards', 'dp', 'dr', 'ds', 'dt', 'du', 'due', 'during', 'dx', 'dy', 'e', 'e2', 'e3', 'ea', 'each', 'ec', 'ed', 'edu', 'ee', 'ef', 'effect', 'eg', 'ei', 'eight', 'eighty', 'either', 'ej', 'el', 'eleven', 'else', 'elsewhere', 'em', 'empty', 'en', 'end', 'ending', 'enough', 'entirely', 'eo', 'ep', 'eq', 'er', 'es', 'especially', 'est', 'et', 'et-al', 'etc', 'eu', 'ev', 'even', 'ever', 'every', 'everybody', 'everyone', 'everything', 'everywhere', 'ex', 'exactly', 'example', 'except', 'ey', 'f', 'f2', 'fa', 'far', 'fc', 'few', 'ff', 'fi', 'fifteen', 'fifth', 'fify', 'fill', 'find', 'fire', 'first', 'five', 'fix', 'fj', 'fl', 'fn', 'fo', 'followed', 'following', 'follows', 'for', 'former', 'formerly', 'forth', 'forty', 'found', 'four', 'fr', 'from', 'front', 'fs', 'ft', 'fu', 'full', 'further', 'furthermore', 'fy', 'g', 'ga', 'gave', 'ge', 'get', 'gets', 'getting', 'gi', 'give', 'given', 'gives', 'giving', 'gj', 'gl', 'go', 'goes', 'going', 'gone', 'got', 'gotten', 'gr', 'greetings', 'gs', 'gy', 'h', 'h2', 'h3', 'had', 'hadn', 'hadn''t', 'happens', 'hardly', 'has', 'hasn', 'hasnt', 'hasn''t', 'have', 'haven', 'haven''t', 'having', 'he', 'hed', 'he''d', 'he''ll', 'hello', 'help', 'hence', 'her', 'here', 'hereafter', 'hereby', 'herein', 'heres', 'here''s', 'hereupon', 'hers', 'herself', 'hes', 'he''s', 'hh', 'hi', 'hid', 'him', 'himself', 'his', 'hither', 'hj', 'ho', 'home', 'hopefully', 'how', 'howbeit', 'however', 'how''s', 'hr', 'hs', 'http', 'hu', 'hundred', 'hy', 'i', 'i2', 'i3', 'i4', 'i6', 'i7', 'i8', 'ia', 'ib', 'ibid', 'ic', 'id', 'i''d', 'ie', 'if', 'ig', 'ignored', 'ih', 'ii', 'ij', 'il', 'i''ll', 'im', 'i''m', 'immediate', 'immediately', 'importance', 'important', 'in', 'inasmuch', 'inc', 'indeed', 'index', 'indicate', 'indicated', 'indicates', 'information', 'inner', 'insofar', 'instead', 'interest', 'into', 'invention', 'inward', 'io', 'ip', 'iq', 'ir', 'is', 'isn', 'isn''t', 'it', 'itd', 'it''d', 'it''ll', 'its', 'it''s', 'itself', 'iv', 'i''ve', 'ix', 'iy', 'iz', 'j', 'jj', 'jr', 'js', 'jt', 'ju', 'just', 'k', 'ke', 'keep', 'keeps', 'kept', 'kg', 'kj', 'km', 'know', 'known', 'knows', 'ko', 'l', 'l2', 'la', 'largely', 'last', 'lately', 'later', 'latter', 'latterly', 'lb', 'lc', 'le', 'least', 'les', 'less', 'lest', 'let', 'lets', 'let''s', 'lf', 'like', 'liked', 'likely', 'line', 'little', 'lj', 'll', 'll', 'ln', 'lo', 'look', 'looking', 'looks', 'los', 'lr', 'ls', 'lt', 'ltd', 'm', 'm2', 'ma', 'made', 'mainly', 'make', 'makes', 'many', 'may', 'maybe', 'me', 'mean', 'means', 'meantime', 'meanwhile', 'merely', 'mg', 'might', 'mightn', 'mightn''t', 'mill', 'million', 'mine', 'miss', 'ml', 'mn', 'mo', 'more', 'moreover', 'most', 'mostly', 'move', 'mr', 'mrs', 'ms', 'mt', 'mu', 'much', 'mug', 'must', 'mustn', 'mustn''t', 'my', 'myself', 'n', 'n2', 'na', 'name', 'namely', 'nay', 'nc', 'nd', 'ne', 'near', 'nearly', 'necessarily', 'necessary', 'need', 'needn', 'needn''t', 'needs', 'neither', 'never', 'nevertheless', 'new', 'next', 'ng', 'ni', 'nine', 'ninety', 'nj', 'nl', 'nn', 'no', 'nobody', 'non', 'none', 'nonetheless', 'noone', 'nor', 'normally', 'nos', 'not', 'noted', 'nothing', 'novel', 'now', 'nowhere', 'nr', 'ns', 'nt', 'ny', 'o', 'oa', 'ob', 'obtain', 'obtained', 'obviously', 'oc', 'od', 'of', 'off', 'often', 'og', 'oh', 'oi', 'oj', 'ok', 'okay', 'ol', 'old', 'om', 'omitted', 'on', 'once', 'one', 'ones', 'only', 'onto', 'oo', 'op', 'oq', 'or', 'ord', 'os', 'ot', 'other', 'others', 'otherwise', 'ou', 'ought', 'our', 'ours', 'ourselves', 'out', 'outside', 'over', 'overall', 'ow', 'owing', 'own', 'ox', 'oz', 'p', 'p1', 'p2', 'p3', 'page', 'pagecount', 'pages', 'par', 'part', 'particular', 'particularly', 'pas', 'past', 'pc', 'pd', 'pe', 'per', 'perhaps', 'pf', 'ph', 'pi', 'pj', 'pk', 'pl', 'placed', 'please', 'plus', 'pm', 'pn', 'po', 'poorly', 'possible', 'possibly', 'potentially', 'pp', 'pq', 'pr', 'predominantly', 'present', 'presumably', 'previously', 'primarily', 'probably', 'promptly', 'proud', 'provides', 'ps', 'pt', 'pu', 'put', 'py', 'q', 'qj', 'qu', 'que', 'quickly', 'quite', 'qv', 'r', 'r2', 'ra', 'ran', 'rather', 'rc', 'rd', 're', 'readily', 'really', 'reasonably', 'recent', 'recently', 'ref', 'refs', 'regarding', 'regardless', 'regards', 'related', 'relatively', 'research', 'research-articl', 'respectively', 'resulted', 'resulting', 'results', 'rf', 'rh', 'ri', 'right', 'rj', 'rl', 'rm', 'rn', 'ro', 'rq', 'rr', 'rs', 'rt', 'ru', 'run', 'rv', 'ry', 's', 's2', 'sa', 'said', 'same', 'saw', 'say', 'saying', 'says', 'sc', 'sd', 'se', 'sec', 'second', 'secondly', 'section', 'see', 'seeing', 'seem', 'seemed', 'seeming', 'seems', 'seen', 'self', 'selves', 'sensible', 'sent', 'serious', 'seriously', 'seven', 'several', 'sf', 'shall', 'shan', 'shan''t', 'she', 'shed', 'she''d', 'she''ll', 'shes', 'she''s', 'should', 'shouldn', 'shouldn''t', 'should''ve', 'show', 'showed', 'shown', 'showns', 'shows', 'si', 'side', 'significant', 'significantly', 'similar', 'similarly', 'since', 'sincere', 'six', 'sixty', 'sj', 'sl', 'slightly', 'sm', 'sn', 'so', 'some', 'somebody', 'somehow', 'someone', 'somethan', 'something', 'sometime', 'sometimes', 'somewhat', 'somewhere', 'soon', 'sorry', 'sp', 'specifically', 'specified', 'specify', 'specifying', 'sq', 'sr', 'ss', 'st', 'still', 'stop', 'strongly', 'sub', 'substantially', 'successfully', 'such', 'sufficiently', 'suggest', 'sup', 'sure', 'sy', 'system', 'sz', 't', 't1', 't2', 't3', 'take', 'taken', 'taking', 'tb', 'tc', 'td', 'te', 'tell', 'ten', 'tends', 'tf', 'th', 'than', 'thank', 'thanks', 'thanx', 'that', 'that''ll', 'thats', 'that''s', 'that''ve', 'the', 'their', 'theirs', 'them', 'themselves', 'then', 'thence', 'there', 'thereafter', 'thereby', 'thered', 'therefore', 'therein', 'there''ll', 'thereof', 'therere', 'theres', 'there''s', 'thereto', 'thereupon', 'there''ve', 'these', 'they', 'theyd', 'they''d', 'they''ll', 'theyre', 'they''re', 'they''ve', 'thickv', 'thin', 'think', 'third', 'this', 'thorough', 'thoroughly', 'those', 'thou', 'though', 'thoughh', 'thousand', 'three', 'throug', 'through', 'throughout', 'thru', 'thus', 'ti', 'til', 'tip', 'tj', 'tl', 'tm', 'tn', 'to', 'together', 'too', 'took', 'top', 'toward', 'towards', 'tp', 'tq', 'tr', 'tried', 'tries', 'truly', 'try', 'trying', 'ts', 't''s', 'tt', 'tv', 'twelve', 'twenty', 'twice', 'two', 'tx', 'u', 'u201d', 'ue', 'ui', 'uj', 'uk', 'um', 'un', 'under', 'unfortunately', 'unless', 'unlike', 'unlikely', 'until', 'unto', 'uo', 'up', 'upon', 'ups', 'ur', 'us', 'use', 'used', 'useful', 'usefully', 'usefulness', 'uses', 'using', 'usually', 'ut', 'v', 'va', 'value', 'various', 'vd', 've', 've', 'very', 'via', 'viz', 'vj', 'vo', 'vol', 'vols', 'volumtype', 'vq', 'vs', 'vt', 'vu', 'w', 'wa', 'want', 'wants', 'was', 'wasn', 'wasnt', 'wasn''t', 'way', 'we', 'wed', 'we''d', 'welcome', 'well', 'we''ll', 'well-b', 'went', 'were', 'we''re', 'weren', 'werent', 'weren''t', 'we''ve', 'what', 'whatever', 'what''ll', 'whats', 'what''s', 'when', 'whence', 'whenever', 'when''s', 'where', 'whereafter', 'whereas', 'whereby', 'wherein', 'wheres', 'where''s', 'whereupon', 'wherever', 'whether', 'which', 'while', 'whim', 'whither', 'who', 'whod', 'whoever', 'whole', 'who''ll', 'whom', 'whomever', 'whos', 'who''s', 'whose', 'why', 'why''s', 'wi', 'widely', 'will', 'willing', 'wish', 'with', 'within', 'without', 'wo', 'won', 'wonder', 'wont', 'won''t', 'words', 'world', 'would', 'wouldn', 'wouldnt', 'wouldn''t', 'www', 'x', 'x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'xf', 'xi', 'xj', 'xk', 'xl', 'xn', 'xo', 'xs', 'xt', 'xv', 'xx', 'y', 'y2', 'yes', 'yet', 'yj', 'yl', 'you', 'youd', 'you''d', 'you''ll', 'your', 'youre', 'you''re', 'yours', 'yourself', 'yourselves', 'you''ve', 'yr', 'ys', 'yt', 'z', 'zero', 'zi', 'zz')
GROUP BY x.Item
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Here's the result of the above code, as you can see it's not counting correctly:

```
Word       Counts
server       2
sql          2
data         1
database     1
popular      1
powerful     1
```

Can anyone help on this? Would be really appreciated!

Comment: Honestly, don't use T-SQL would be my answer. Use *anything* that has better™ text manipulation features. The fact that you are on a read-only instance further cements this, in my opinion, as CLR isn't even an option.

Comment: Not to mention that even *if* you "had" (which I would suggest you don't) to do it in T-SQL, helper functions would make the answer *far* easier. The fact that you don't use `STRING_SPLIT` also suggests you are on SQL Server 2014?

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `String_split` here, such as

```
select value Word, Count(*) Counts
from words
cross apply String_Split(text_column, ' ')
where value not in(exclude list)
group by value
order by counts desc;
```

Comment: value is a reserved word -- you might want to escape it.

Comment: It's a keyword, but not a *reserved keyword*, @Hogan . As such, it doesn't need escaping.

Comment: Thanks - [value] is optional if that's preferred, however it's syntactically correct.

Comment: good point -- values is the reserved word

Comment: It *is*, however, an [ODBC Reserved Keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#odbc-reserved-keywords), so if you are using ODBC delimit identifying it is important.

Answer (score 0):

You should should the string_split function -- like this

```
SELECT id, value as aword  
FROM words
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(text_column, ',');
```

This will create a table with all the words by id -- to get the count do this:

```
SELECT aword, count(*) as counts
FROM (
  SELECT id, value as aword  
  FROM words
  CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(text_column, ',');  
) x
GROUP BY aword
```

You may need to lower case the LOWER(text_column) if you want it to not matter

Comment: Word of "warning" that this won't take grammar into consideration. So for a simple sentence like "What's the last letter in last?" it would list `last` and `last?` as 2 different "words".

Comment: @Larnu -- true-- probably need to filter the data -- upper case it and remove all non letter characters besides space

Comment: Which raises a different issue, @Hogan, such as "it's" and "its" being different words, but now being counted as the same. I'm not trying to say that the attempt is "wrong", but just providing further reasons as to why T-SQL just *isn't* a good choice for this; it has *no concept* of what a "word" is.

Comment: The many language  idiosyncrasies can quickly compound to make a trivial process far more complex - would that *it's* be expanded to it-is or used as possessive depending on context - the simple solution may be acceptable for the OP's requirements, it may not, or the OP might not have even considered plurals, punctuation etc, or need to.

Comment: @Stu -- all good points.  SQL Server does support Full Text Search (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver16),  depending on the use-case (which the user does not fully explain) it may be that is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to STRING_SPLIT function, you can use weird xml trick to convert space to a word node and then shred it with nodes function:

```
select word, COUNT(*)
from (
    select n.value('.', 'nvarchar(50)') AS word
    from (
        VALUES
        (1, 'SQL Server is a popular database management system'),
        (2, 'It is widely used for data storage and retrieval'),
        (3, 'SQL Server is a powerful tool for data analysis')
        ) AS t (id, txt)
     CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT  CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(txt, ' ', '</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) x
        ) x
    CROSS APPLY x.nodes('x') z(n)
    ) w
GROUP BY word
```

Of course, this will fail on "bad" words and invalid xml-characters but it can be worked on. Text processing has never been SQL Server's strong-point though, so probably better to use some NLP library to do this kind of stuff